# Find the intersection of $z=1-x^2$ and $x=y^3$ in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, surfaces

I have these 2 surfaces, given in their Cartesian form, and want to find the resulting surface of intersection.

My approach is to find parametric representations. But I have two approaches, and not sure if both approaches are proper, or if one or the other is only proper.

Here are the equations:

$$\tag{1}z = 1 - x^2$$

$$\tag{2}x = y^3$$

**Approach 1**:

Substitute (2) into (1),  we get the cartesian form of the intersection surface: $z = 1 - x^6$, then try to parameterize this, but I run into $2$ independent parameters with this approach.

**Approach 2**: Direct parameterization:

Just looking at both equations I see that '$x$' is the common variable so I set $x= t$. Then just plugging in '$t$' into the equations, and put them together in $(x,y,z)$, I get:
$$(x,y,z) = (t, t^{1/3}, 1-t^2)$$

So not sure if either of these 2 approaches above give the correct parameterization.

Not sure if there is a systematic procedure to do parameterization of surfaces of intersection in $\mathbb R^3$, or if this is a creative type of process, and hence there is no systematic procedure to follow.

Hope someone can explain how to think about this kind of problem.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.  Approach #2 is correct for this problem

Comment: Hi, thanks for the MathJax tutorial. Thanks for giving your input that Approach#2 is the correct way.

Comment: The resulting *curve* of intersection! Use $y=t$; why?

Comment: Hi, I thought about using y =t, which would give the same type of equation in Approach#1. But for some reason, I don't like high order polynomials like having z=1-t^6, and x = t^3.

Comment: I guess you can say I am biased against high order polynomials for some reason when it comes to parametric curves

Comment: Hi there, Prof.  Shifrin! I am honored that you are on here on stackoverflow and provided some input on my question. Just wanted to say I have your multivariable calculus book. I really like how your book builds up all the concepts in a very nice pedagogical style, leading to differential forms. I think your book is the best to get into the realm of differential forms! So once again I am honored to get your input here.

Comment: you should tag @TedShifrin otherwise he may not get notification for your comment. I did that now :)

Comment: Ok, so if you do the tag anywhere in this post, then the person will get notification. I did not know that. Thank you so much for that @math-lover

Comment: Hope I got your handle correct, I saw that is how it is in the URL. Because your name has a space, how does one deal with that case, for sake of notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two quick comments. First, you do not want to introduce $t^{1/3}$, as then the parametrization will not be differentiable — let alone smooth — at the origin.

Second, when you eliminate a variable as you did in approach 1, you are not done; rather, you've obtained the *projection* of the intersection into the $xz$-plane in this case. You still need to give the $y$ value for each point on that curve in the $xz$-plane.  To convince yourself, consider the system of linear equations $x+y=0$, $2x-y=0$. If you eliminate $y$, you get $3x=0$, so $x=0$. Clearly the solution set is not the entire $y$-axis.

Oh, and glad you enjoy the book. There are also lectures on YouTube, linked in my profile.

Comment: Yes, I have run into a similar situation when dealing with cartesian based equations, like you are saying, you only get the projection onto a particular plane in R3. I had a similar problem with a plane going thru a sphere, which led to an eqn of an ellipse, which was the projection of the actual circle of intersection projected onto one of the planes of R3. Thanks @TedShifrin

Comment: I not forgot the kindness also of Ted :-) +1.

Comment: But now the question I have, does finding a parametrization in terms of 't', does it directly give me the "True" intersection of the Surfaces.

Comment: Yes, check the “if and only if” or containment both ways.

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean from "if and only if" and with your wording of "containment both ways". I know that with the example I provided in the comment, with Cartesian equations you get the projection onto one of the planes, but then one has to do a lot of work to get it to the true intersection  equation. Derive more equations geometrically basically.

Comment: But that is what is not really explained in books like from Stewart. I am going thru Stewarts 8th edition and it does not really talk to this point.

Comment: In the case of your circle on the sphere, projection is not the clever approach; you want to use linear algebra to use a better orthonormal basis. You can of course still do it with the projection. You have two sets in your question — one given by the two equations, the other given parametrically. You want to show these two sets are equal.

Comment: Don’t expect rigor from standard engineering calculus texts. The audience is very different. And most calculus books have rather poor treatment (even in terms of intuition) of multivariable topics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply on this @TedShifrin. SO what I gather is that as long as my parameterization does the job for the given set of cartesian equations, then that will  truly represent the intersection equation. But I just wanted to add that there is a problem with books, in terms of the jump from Calculus to Analysis. Calculus does a good job generally in terms of the details of computations, but miss out on important certain topics like this particular one here. BUT Analysis books, they go too far in theory, and skip how to do all the new kinds of computations in Analysis.

Comment: In Analysis books, they assume that you know all forms of computations. When in Analysis there are ways of computations that are not taught in Calculus. SO this is where there is a gap in being able to transition from Calculus to Analysis.

Comment: Well, that's why you have my book. It is very much a concrete analysis treatment. Students who did well in my course had little difficulty taking abstract algebra and baby Rudin the next year(s).

Comment: SO, just wanted to say Thanks for all your efforts to help me out. I did Vector Calculus back in the 90's. But I have been going back to math from time to time, to try to challenge my Math level of understanding on and off for over 20 years. I really love doing  math, in terms of Undergraduate level math from Calculus to Analysis to Number theory to Complex Analysis.

Comment: There is a great need of books that would be Transition books from Calculus to Analysis, and I consider your book one of the only ones of its kind to try to bridge the GAP between Calculus and Analysis! I wish there were more people out there filing this gap.